# Laravel validation: exists two column same row

Tags: php, laravel, validation, rules

Is there a way of referencing another field when specifying the exists validation rule in Laravel?

My request :

```
public function rules()
    {

        return [
            'numero_de_somme' => 'unique:personnels,numero_de_somme|exists:fonctionnaire,num_somme',
            'cin' => 'unique:personnels,cin|exists:fonctionnaire,cin',

        ];
    }
```

in my validation rules I want to be able to make sure that:

- `num_somme` exists within the `fonctionnaire` table
- `cin` exists within the fonctionnaire table and `cin` input must be
  on the same row of the `num_somme`

num_somme : 12345    cin :   s89745

num_somme : 78945    cin :   U10125

Explaining : for example

- 1st scenario if the input `num_somme` = 12345 and `cin` = U10125 the validation must fail
- 2nd scenario if the input `num_somme` = 12345 and `cin` = s89745 the validation must success

I hope this makes sense.

Thank you

Answer (score 16):

You can simply use this:

```
'request_input' => exists:table,col,alternative_col_1,alternative_val_1,alternative_col_2,alternative_val_2, ...'
```

The SQL query is like below:

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `table` where `id` = [request_input] and `alternative_col1` = "alternative_val1" and `alternative_col2` = "alternative_val2"
```

Comment: This syntax for `exists` was outdated and obtuse in 2019 and is even more so now. The `Rule` class has been a better alternative since Laravel 5.3.

Answer (score 6):

I came across the same need today and I think I have a solution using the validation Rule class: [Rule example](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-exists).

Here is my scenario: I have an email verifications table and I want to ensure that a passed machine code and activation code exist on the same row.

Be sure to include `use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;`

```
$activationCode = $request->activation_code;                                   

$rules = [                                                                     
    'mc' => [                                                                  
        'required',                                                            
        Rule::exists('email_verifications', 'machineCode')                     
        ->where(function ($query) use ($activationCode) {                      
            $query->where('activationCode', $activationCode);                  
        }),                                                                    
    ],                                                                         
    'activation_code' => 'required|integer|min:5',                             
    'operating_system' => 'required|alpha_num|max:45'                          
];
```

The first argument in the exists method is the table and the second is the custom column name I'm using for the 'mc' field. I pass the second column I want to check using the 'use' keyword and then use that field in a a where clause.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve validating multipe columns by using **Rule**.

Include :

`use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;`

`use Validator;`

```
$AdminId = $request->AdminId;
$Validate = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'TaxId' => [ 'required', Rule::exists('tax','id')                     
                                    ->where(function ($query) use ($AdminId) {                      
                                    $query->where('u_id', $AdminId);                  
                                    })], 
    ]);
if($Validate->fails())
        {`Your ERROR HERE`}
else
        {`SUCCESS`}
```

Here in my example I'm checking u_id and Id which is in same row and 2 columns.

Explaining : for example

My DB HAS 2 ROWS IN tax TABLE

**id = 1 , u_id = 1, tax = "GST" , value -> 8**

**id = 2 , u_id = 2, tax = "GST" , value -> 5**

1st scenario if the input **id = 2 and u_id = 1** the validation must **fail** because this row belongs to u_id = 2.

2nd scenario if the input **id = 2 and u_id = 2** the validation must **success**

Answer (score 1):

i managed to solve it using the most simple method

- for `numero_de_somme`

`'numero_de_somme' => 'unique:personnels,numero_de_somme|exists:fonctionnaire,num_somme,cin,'.Request::get('cin'),`

- for `cin`

`'cin' => 'unique:personnels,cin|exists:fonctionnaire,cin',`

**PS** . don't forget to call `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Comment: With num_somme on the exista rule you’re referring again to numero_de_somme?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to go about it using the `Rule` class. Technically, it's redundant to have the `exist` Rule twice.

Both `exists` rules check the exact same thing and do then same query to the database.

```php
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

public function rules()
{
    $data = $this->validationData();

    $cin = $this->has('cin')
        ? $data['cin']
        : null;

    $num_somme = $this->has('numero_de_somme')
        ? $data['numero_de_somme']
        : null;

    return [
        'numero_de_somme' => [
            Rule::unique('personnels', 'numero_de_somme'),
            Rule::exists('fonctionnaire', 'num_somme')->where('cin', $cin),
        ],
        'cin' => [
            Rule::unique('personnels', 'cin'),
            Rule::exists('fonctionnaire', 'cin')->where('num_somme', $num_somme),
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: I would do `$cin = $this->cin; $num_somme = $this->numero_de_somme;` since `Request::_get()` defaults to null. Is there an advantage to using `Request::validationData()`? I haven't seen it before.

Comment: And +1 for being the only answer to actually use the column names from the question instead of just copying from something else lol

Comment: `$this->cin` and `$this->numero_de_somme` could work too, yeah. I don't know if it's an advantage, but `$this->validationData()` does *something* to the request's data. I think it just combines the inputs and the files but there's also a loop I'm *not quite sure* about what it's doing.... but the main thing is that `$this->validationData()` is what is passed to the `FormRequest`'s validator so I use it to make sure there's no weird thing going on.

Answer (score -1):

```
   if (is_numeric($request->get('emailOrphone'))){
  $request->validate([
      'emailOrphone'=>'exists:users,phone',
  ],
  [
      'emailOrphone.exists'=>'phone is invalid.'
  ]);
 }else{
     $request->validate([
         'emailOrphone'=>'exists:users,email',
     ],
         [
             'emailOrphone.exists'=>'email is invalid.''
         ]);
 }
```