# Check if 2 fields' value exists on the same row using Laravel Validator

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have an array of multiple rows.

As of now I can check if field `taskCode` exists in the table of `tbl_projtask`

using Validator.

Now I need to check if `projCode` and `taskCode` exists in the same row.

This is the sample data of `tbl_projtask`

[image]

I have this working code that validates if `taskCode` exists in the table or not.

```
//Task Code Validations
            foreach ($arr4 as $rowValidate4) {

                $validate_data4[] = array(
                    'projCode'  =>  $projCodeValidate,
                    'taskCode'  =>   $rowValidate4['task_code'],
                    'taskWeight'  =>  $rowValidate4['weight'],
                    'plan_days' =>  $rowValidate4['planned_days'],
                    'actual_days'  =>  $rowValidate4['actual_days'],
                    'deleted'  =>  0,
                    'by_id'  => auth()->user()->id,
                    'updated_by'    =>  auth()->user()->name,
                    'created_at'    =>  now(),
                    'updated_at'    => now(),
                );

                $ttlTaskWeight += $rowValidate4['weight'];
            }
            $validatorSave4 = Validator::make(
                $validate_data4,
                [
                    '*.projCode' => "required",
                    '*.taskCode' => "required|exists:tbl_projtask,taskCode",
                    '*.taskWeight' => "required",
                    '*.plan_days' => "required",
                    '*.actual_days' => "required",
                ],
                [
                    '*.taskCode.exists' => 'The selected :attribute is invalid. Task Code does not exists!',
                ]
            );

       if($validatorSave4->fails()){
                return redirect()
                ->back()
                ->with(['errors'=>$validatorSave4->errors()->all()])
                ->with('modal',$modal);
            }
```

Didn't include the whole codes just the important part. As of now my validator can check if `1 field` exists in the record. But what I'm trying to do is to check if `2fields` exists in the same row these fields are `projCode` and `taskCode`

**UPDATE**

I found this helpful thread same situation but in this thread. Column value is not coming from an array.

This thread uses `Laravel Rule` to check if `field` exists or not.

[Laravel validation: exists two column same row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44437772/laravel-validation-exists-two-column-same-row)

In my case, my column values are coming from my arrays. Is there any solution for this situation?