# Can I have two "exists" validations for laravel model?

Tags: laravel, validation

I have `Units` table, it has `name` and `abbreviation`. In my create rules for `BillOfMaterials`, can I use an `exists` for both the `name` and `abbreviation`? Both are not null, example:

```php
'unit_of_measure' => 'required|string|max:255|exists:units,abbreviation',
'unit_of_measure' => 'required|string|max:255|exists:units,name',
```

Comment: What does `unit_of_measure` contain? For this to work, the abbreviation would always have to be the same as the name; that's not likely. If you want `unit_of_measure` to be *either* the name or the abbreviation, and to check one or the other exists, you might be better off with a custom validator rule.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/54128746/5882307